# Google Map API Key Authorization failure

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, authorization, android-mapview

I am **adding a Google map into a fragment** 
using MapView like this :

```
public HotspotPageFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private void initGoogleMap(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mapView = (MapView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.mapView_hotspot);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume();
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this seems to work for adding a google map.

But now I get an error message about **Authorization failure**

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  
Please see    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: AIzaSyAMQNk********kCx8p-uz8******1t75s
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 5A:A1:E4:**:07:BF:E2:**:A3:F0:B6:**:04:4E:0A:**:2A:B6:B4:6B;com.example.androidwork.foodsharing
```

I have checked that the API key is right ...
I have no idea how to solve it :(

here is my manifest looks like :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <!-- Google map -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
...
```

and this is the result

[image]

thanks.

And this indicates I have enabled it right ?

[image]

Comment: did you enable Google Maps Android API v2"  ?

Comment: .. I am confused where to enable ? please tell me ><  I can't find any option at Google Console

Comment: ok wait let me show u

Comment: Did you found any solution? I am facing similar issue with everything proper. Checklist -> Manifest permissions and meta with API key, enabling google map API v2, displaying map on screen, using proper keystore

Comment: Also it was working with my temporary different API key. For that I have once I have cleared cache and data. And second time uninstalled whole app and then reinstalled. But still same

Answer (score 0):

check in your google api console where is the api is enable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1- check that you've enabled the Maps API v2

2- check your SHA-1 fingerprint

3- if you haven't done it, restrict the api to your package name

Comment: where to check if the Maps API V2 Enabled ? I can't find the option in Google Console

Comment: and I have restricted the api to the package name :(

Answer (score 0):

**CREAT SHA1 KEY AND PASTE API CONSOLE** [see this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

Answer (score 0):

Update googleplayservices on your phone
and check if those are in the gradle:

dependencies {

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

first go to google console under credentials item in menu and create a credential key for android map api ( if  not exist ) , it will tell you it is going to take some time to be enabled , and in your dependencies all you have to do is to add google play services it will handle every thing for google except google client and auths , then try this code in your app

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

   LatLng latlang= new LatLng("latitude", "longitude");
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlang).title("Marker in latlang"));
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlang, 18));
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

 }
```